# If labels are equal change view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string, comparison

hi I got this code and when I hit button a lot of things happen, images get set etc. But I also want it to compare 2 labels and when They are equal I want it to change view. It doesn't work can someone have a look why?

```
-(IBAction)play {

if (labelsText.text == textview.text){

    GoedwoordViewController *Goedwoord = [[GoedwoordViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:Goedwoord animated:YES];
}
```

labelsText is my input label, textview is a label in which a random word will appear.

GoedwoordViewController is the destination view. and GameViewController is the current view.

hope someone knows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change Following line...

```
 if ([labelsText.text isEqualToString textview.text])
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: I was going to answer the same, +1

Comment: @user1349949: If it's help than Do accept the answer not for me but for the beginner(or other user who might have same problem). So, they can make decision that which is best and..

Comment: sorry must have misclicked! Thought I did

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
if(someString==anotherString){}
```

You're checking if the pointer of `someString` is the same of `anotherString`, so never use `==` to compare strings.
The best is to use the @Nit solution that check if the strings are equals.